# Bug in Careers. HTML code showing in Edit location field

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In Careers, in the edit profile page, you can modify the location of where you are looking for employment. When a location is present, I see this verbatim HTML code in the page right above the textbox and the "remove" link,

`<input id="cvLocationId" name="cvLocationId" type="hidden" value="41244" />`

If I am not clear enough, please let me know, and I can provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  Thanks for the report!